Inversion in conditionals
We use "inversion" to sound more formal.
1 If you look for John, I will help.
1 Should you look for John, I will help you.
We are also allowed use the conitnuous version:
2 If you're looking for John, I will help.
Can we then use:
2 Should you be looking for John, I will help you
Is that correct?
3 If you have done it, she will be happy
I don't think "inversion" is possible with three
To sum it up, is my 2 example correct and what about 3?

#1 and #2 are okay but stiff by today's style. #3 could be "Should you have it done already, she will be happy."

The point is that "should you [verb]* equals If you [verb] semantically. Should you [verb] is not more formal. It is just different.
